# How to query Metadata from a WebDAV server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, webdav

I am trying to create an iPhone App that will talk to a WebDAV Server. I have no idea on this.
Specifically in reference to:

1. How to upload a file to the WebDAV Server
2. How to download a file from the WebDAV server
3. How to retrieve / Add MetaData on the WebDAV server
4. How to enumerate directories & files on a WebDAV server

Comment: The metadata part I too need some help finding out. I mean exif metadata, not basic file attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol is defined in [RFC 2616 (HTTP/1.1)](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html) and [RFC 4918 (WebDAV)](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html):

1. PUT
2. GET
3. PROPFIND/PROPPATCH
4. PROPFIND (Depth:1)

Comment: Some Code, specially for the iPhone would be really helpful. Things like what should the header look like to retrieve properties. Do you use a NSURLRequest or do you use a HTTPStream or an XML Stream and so on.

Comment: Jayant: it would be good to give it a shot first. People aren't going to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

For all basic CRUD operations, use an existing library such as :

- https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider
- https://github.com/Isvvc/WebDAV-Swift

Regarding EXIF metadata, I'm not aware of any mechanism able to access these through WebDAV protocol. For the time being, I recommend you to download the file and extract its metadata. For sure, this method does not work for searching and filtering several files on the server. It is only working in case you want to show these metadata for one particular file.